# XML or text file logging in aspnet with thread safe

Tags: asp.net, xml, thread-safety, locking, text-files

I need very simple text file logging. I'll only append lines to it. never change existing ones nor delete them. If it would be XML file it would be easier to bind to grids to view them. but question remains for both text files and xml files as they are in file system.

in web server there will be file locking while appending log entries. and maybe also while reading them. So this method has to be thread safe. At the same moment multiple instances can write date to file.

I know there are some third party tools like serilog etc but I want to know:

how can I append (not change) lines to text file (or xml file) without concerning about file locks ?

if I read xml file to dataset, add a new row to it and save it as xml I would use other entries made by other instances.

if I open a text file with streamwriter and append a line to it, other instances would get lock error.

I get the list of logs from admin panel again, file will be locked and instances wouldn't append logs.

any ideas ?

Comment: *without concerning about file locks* you can't. Absolutely cannot.  Nope.  No.  What you can do is create a single thread that runs in the background that takes items from a collection and writes them to disk, and lock access to that collection on read/write.  Or just use one of many thread safe logging frameworks such as NLog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long reserch hours and experiments I found out that using Nlog is the best option for me. most important thing is people who use it are very happy. I created small example page that writes a log everytime it called and tested it. I have a multithreaded application that calls this sample page  again and again. If was fast enough so I could not see the counting numbers of threads. no problem raised so far.

So, I'll stick to Nlog.

best.